# Mongoose/MongoDB Get mostly viewed articles grouped within a day

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, aggregation-framework

I am trying to clone a Reddit-like community board API using MongoDB + Mongoose on Node.js.

My sample JSON data looks like below:

```js
            {
                "genre": "free",
                "viewCount": 90,
                "isDeleted": false,
                "commentCount": 0,
                "voteCount": 0,
                "_comments": [],
                "_vote": [],
                "_id": "ObjectId",
                "title": "blahblah",
                "contents": "blah",
                "createdAt": "2020-01-24T08:50:28.409Z",
                "__v": 0,
                "id": "5e2aafd4395bf593aa94b623"
            },
```

To solve this problem, I simply sorted using `.sort({ viewCount:-1, createdAt: -1 })`.

However, when I sorted in this way, the most recently created Post will be always come first, even though other posts have larger `viewCount` values...

The next thing I'm thinking of is trying to group Posts data by each day (i.e. All posts created today is grouped together; All posts created yesterday is grouped together).

After grouping, then maybe I can sort the rest of data by `viewCount`.

I believe the method using `aggregate` would be the one possible solution, but I'd like to know if there would be the simplest and the best solution for this problem!

The output I'd like to get is something like this:

```js
// viewcount in Descending Order
{ '2020-01-24': 
{ post1: { viewcount: 999, contents: ...}, 
{ post2: { viewcount: 998, contents:... }, 
... } }, 
'2020-01-23':  
{ post1: { viewcount: 999, contents: ...}, 
{ post2: { viewcount: 998, contents:... }, 
... }, 
'2020-01-22':  
{ post1: { viewcount: 999, contents: ...}, 
{ post2: { viewcount: 998, contents:... }, 
... }, ...}
```

Please help me out here...

Thank you :)

Comment: Yes, using aggregation is the way to do it (_group Posts data by each day_). See this example  from [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#group-by-day-of-the-year).

Comment: So if I would want to group by a day and preserve the origianl data, then should I use $$Root ??

Comment: Group by day and get the `max` of viewCount. How do you want the output look like?

Comment: This will give you the result: (1) sort by day (asc) and view count (desc), and (2) group by day and take the first ($first) document ($$ROOT) for each group. Then use `$project` to shape the final output.

Comment: You can edit your post and include the output there

Comment: You can use any of these two queries: `db.test.aggregate( [ { $sort: { createdAt: -1, viewCount: -1} } ] )` _or_ `db.test.find( { } ).sort( { createdAt: -1, viewCount: -1 } )`.

Comment: Okay. So I guess first use $group to group by each day ,then sort like above would work?

Comment: Did you run the query and see what it is?

Comment: Thanks prasad. I will post the output once I get to use my laptop :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This aggregation gives something similar to the output you are expecting:

```
db.test.aggregate( [ 
  { $sort: { createdAt: -1, viewCount: -1} },
  { $group: { _id: "$createdAt", post: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },
  { $project: { post: 1, date: "$_id", _id: 0 } }
] )
```